# Enable popcnt in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, dpdk

I have Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.8 RC1 and installed the stable version of Debian.

With this version of VirtualBox i can use this command to enable SSE4.1 and SSE4.2:

> VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/SSE4.1 1

I wanted to compile the dpdk, http://dpdk.org, but there is an error:

> "implicit declaration of function ‘_mm_popcnt_u32’

When i am looking at the flags with

> cat /proc/cpuinfo
>
> flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 lahf_lm

There is no "popcnt". Why? Can i enable it or what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [POPCNT is not part of the SSE4.2 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT). Intel implemented POPCNT the same time as SSE4.2 in Nahalem but that does not mean VirtualBox supports it. VirtualBox does not support AVX either.

Answer (score 1):

My case: `POPCNT` is missing on VirtualBox v6.1.22 with Hyper-V.

1. Run
   `VBoxManage setextradata VMName VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/POPCNT`
2. enable *nested paging* on the VM.

It works.

Comment: There should be `1` (value argument) at the end of command line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__builtin_popcountll`  to replace `_mm_popcnt_u32`, so that only sse3 intrinsics are pulled in and used

See here:
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.dpdk.devel/4560